# How to name a static variable that's used for holding the data?

Tags: php, naming-conventions, naming

I have this class :

```
class categories
{
    private static $previousCategories;

     public static function hold_previous_categories($bussId)
     { 
               $query = " SELECT categories .... where businessId  = $bussId "; 

               //run query -> fetch result and save categories at the static variables
               static::$previousCategories = $result;
     }


}
```

I will call hold_previous_categories at first , to save the previous categories at the static variables, later at the end of the script I will use this static variable.

How should I name hold_previous_categories function and $previousCategories static variable ?

Comment: Specify your programming language, Different follow different practices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method names**

All method names are written in lowerCamelCase. ln order to avoid problems with different ﬁlesystems. only the characters a-z, A-Z and 0-9 are allowed for method names - don't use special
characters.

Make method names descriptive, but keep them concise at the same time. Constructors must always be called _conscruct( ), never use the class name as a method name.

a. myMethod( )

b. someNiceMethodNa.me( )

c. betterwriteLongMethodNamesThanNamesNobodyunderstands( )

d. singYmcaLoudly()

e. _construct()

**Variable Names**

Variable names are written in lowercamelcase and should be

a. self-explanatory
 b. not shortened beyond recognition. but rather longer if it makes their meaning clearer

The following example shows two variables with the same meaning but different naming. You'll surely agree the longer versions are better (don't you ...‘?).

Correct naming of variables

a. $singletonObjectsRegistry

b. $argumentsArray

c. $aLotOfHtmlCode

Incorrect naming of variables

a. $aObjRgstry

b. $argArr

c. $cx

Comment: thank you for your answer, could you please suggest a names for my function and static variables that appear in my question.

Comment: variable name is fine as per the coding standards and change the function name to "holdPreviousCategories"